# What is this initialization with braces after constructor call?

Tags: c#, interface, initialization

I'm trying to learn about Interfaces in C# and came upon this code from Microsoft's github examples:

```
SampleCustomer c = new SampleCustomer("customer one", new DateTime(2010, 5, 31))
{
    Reminders =
    {
        { new DateTime(2010, 08, 12), "childs's birthday" },
        { new DateTime(1012, 11, 15), "anniversary" }
    }
};
```

I understand that SampleCustomer is a constructor, but how is it that Reminders is included in the Constructor for SampleCustomer?

SampleCustomer looks like this:

```
public class SampleCustomer : ICustomer
{
    public SampleCustomer(string name, DateTime dateJoined) =>
        (Name, DateJoined) = (name, dateJoined);
    
    private Dictionary<DateTime, string> _reminders = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
    public IDictionary<DateTime, string> Reminders => _reminders;
}
```

And ICustomer's Reminders is defined in ICustomer as

```
IDictionary<DateTime, string> Reminders { get; }
```

And implemented in SampleCustomer

Comment: Suggested reading: **[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)**

Comment: `Reminders` is readonly, so you can only initialize it via constructor or with this object initialization syntax. Interestingly you are initializing the private `_reminders` field by assigning a value to the public readonly property `Reminders`.

Comment: So I should be able to initialize any public field or property within the object at the time of creation, without creating some kind of convoluted constructor.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This syntax doesn't actually assign any object to readonly `Reminders`. The syntax gets translated to a series of `Reminders.Add(...);` calls, without any assignment.

Comment: @Orion: ok, but it also initializes the private field `_reminders`

Comment: @TimSchmelter It doesn't initialize the private field `_reminders`, that field is initialized in its definition inside the `SampleCustomer` class with `= new Dictionary...`. Neither the property nor the field get re-initialized or re-assigned anytime later, it only gets its `.Add()` method invoked.

Answer (score 2):

In that piece or code thare are 2 different concepts/language features.

One is "Object initializers":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or properties of an object at creation time without having to invoke a constructor followed by lines of assignment statements.

the other is  "Collection intializers":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers

```
var moreNumbers = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {19, "nineteen" },
    {23, "twenty-three" },
    {42, "forty-two" }
};
```

But in this case you are not instantiating a new dictionary but [adding elements to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers-with-collection-read-only-property-initialization)

> You will not be able to use collection initializer syntax discussed so far since the property cannot be assigned a new list
>
> However, new entries can be added to Cats (Reminders in your case) nonetheless using the initialization syntax by omitting the list creation

Comment: Thanks Tim for pointing that out, i missed that one

Comment: I'm still weaiting for someone explaining why it's valid to initialize that `readonly` property that references the private field with this syntax or quote the relevant documentation.

Comment: had to go re read docs to actually get it, it is clearly explained in htat document, i need to re edit the answer

Comment: I totally was not aware of the last part of my answer... good to know!

Answer (score 0):

THats an acceptable initialization syntax. (an unusual one though, because it uses a constructor with arguments and public property initialization)

see here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers